# Duplicate columns in Hibernate generated Select Query

Tags: hibernate

I have an issue with HSQL statements generated by hibernate where I the Select query is having DUPLICATE columns when fetching an Entity along with its one to many counterpart. My class definitions looks like the below;

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "SCHOOL")
public Class School implements Serializable {
   @Id
   private long id;

   @Column(name="NAME")
   private String name;

   @Column(name="ZIP_CODE")
   private String zipCode;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name="NAME", referencedColumnName="SCHOOL_NAME")
   private Set<Student> students= new HashSet<Student>();

  /*
   *
   *followed by other variable definitions, getters and setters
   */
}



@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public Class Student implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column(name="FNAME")
    private String fName;

    @Column(name="LNAME")
    private String lName;

    @Column(name="SCHOOL_NAME")
    private String schoolName;

    @Column(name="DOB")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

   /*
    *
    *followed by other variable definitions, getters and setters
    */
}
```

I have the following Criteria to fetch schools and corresponding students in a specific zipcode.

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(School.class); 
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("zipCode", 56789));
List<School> schools = criteria.list();
```

Above criteria is generating following HSQL in the background with duplicate column entries for STUDENT columns in the SELECT query.

```
select
    this_.ZIP_CODE as ZIP_CODE1_16_3_,
    this_.name as NAME_16_3_,
    this_.LICENSE_NUM as LICENSE_N3_16_3_,

    student3_.FNAME as ZIP_CODE1_16_5_,
    student3_.LNAME as NAME_16_5_,
    student3_.GRADE as GRADE4_16_5_,
    student3_.ETHNICITY as ETHNICITY5_16_5_,
    student3_.SCHOOL_NAME as SCHOOL_NA6_16_5_,

    student3_.FNAME as ZIP_CODE1_14_5_,
    student3_.LNAME as NAME_14_5_,
    student3_.GRADE as GRADE4_14_5_,
    student3_.ETHNICITY as ETHNICITY5_14_5_,
    student3_.SCHOOL_NAME as SCHOOL_NA6_14_5_,

    student3_.FNAME as ZIP_CODE1_14_1_,
    student3_.LNAME as NAME_14_1_,
    student3_.GRADE as GRADE4_14_1_,
    student3_.ETHNICITY as ETHNICITY5_14_1_,
    student3_.SCHOOL_NAME as SCHOOL_NA6_14_1_
from
    SCHOOL this_,
    STUDENT student3_
where
    and this_.name=student3_.SCHOOL_NAME(+)
    and this_.ZIP_CODE=56789;
```

(Above query has been tweaked little bit before posting the same here.)

Please suggest a solution using which I can get rid of the duplicate columns in SELECT query.

Note: I am using hibernate 4.2.7 and hibernate-jpa-2.0-api

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with a similar query, and very similar entity, did you found any solution for this?